# Access denied when installing software from network storage on domain computer

Tags: windows, domain, installation, file-permissions

When attempting to install software (from network storage) on a domain joined computer two prompts show up asking for user credential. One is asking for Administrator account to install software and second is asking for account to access the installation file. Even when administrator account is used for both prompts there is still access denied error. Administrator account does have access to installation file and does have rights to install software.

Alternatively, copying file to a local machine first and then attempting to install it using administrator account credentials does indeed work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running the install from an elevated command prompt that maps the network storage prior to running the install.  (Basically, when you elevate the process it doesn't have access to the network share, because it's its own session and doesn't have access to the same resources your regular account has.)